# syntax error:missing after property id mongo shell 4:5

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm getting syntax error

> missing after property id@shell:4:5

```
db.movieDetails.updateOne({
    title:"The Martian"
} , {
    $set {
        poster:"http://howle.jpg"
       }
})
```

```html
db.movieDetails.updateOne({
    title:"The Martian"
} , {
    $set {
        poster:"http://howle.jpg"
       }
})
```

Comment: `$set {` is not valid javascript syntax

Comment: To make that clear the message actually says "Synatax error" **`:`** which is the "colon" is missing. Was that not descriptive enough an error?

Comment: thank you. yes colon was missing

Answer (score 0):

```
db.movieDetails.updateOne({
    title:"The Martian"
} , {
    $set:{
        poster:"http://howle.jpg"
       }
})
```

Missing : at $set operator

[$set_Operator_Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939100/syntax-errormissing-after-property-id-mongo-shell-45?answertab=oldest#tab-top@Ratan uday kumar Thank you